# How do I prevent two pipeline jenkins jobs of the same type to run in parallel on the same node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I do not want to allow two jobs of the same type (same repository) to run in parallel on the same node.

How can I do this using groovy inside Jenkinsfile ?

Answer (score 84):

The answer provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43963315/6839445 is deprecated.

The current method to disable concurrent builds is to set options:

```
options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
```

Detailed description is available here:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

Comment: I'm trying this and it disables concurrent builds globally, OP wants to disable concurrent builds per node but still allow more than one build to occur at the same time, just one per available node.

Comment: This is working for our particular purpose, although it bothers me that we have to configure this in the pipeline and that it can't just be done globally somehow.

Answer (score 51):

You got at the disableConcurrentBuilds property:

```
properties properties: [
  ...
  disableConcurrentBuilds(),
  ...
]
```

Then the job would wait the older one to finish first

Comment: I think this is the most sensible response

Comment: This solution is unfortunately deprecated. Options should be used as described in another answer.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with this? the snippet generator still shows this option for scripted pipelines. Do you have a link to the mentioned deprecation?

Answer (score 41):

Another way is to use the Lockable Resources plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

You can define locks (mutexes) however you want and can put variables in the names. E.g. to prevent multiple jobs from using a compiler concurrently on a build node:

```
stage('Build') {
    lock(resource: "compiler_${env.NODE_NAME}", inversePrecedence: true) {
      milestone 1
      sh "fastlane build_release"
    }
}
```

So if you wanted to prevent more than one job of the same branch running concurrently per node you could do something like

```
stage('Build') {
    lock(resource: "lock_${env.NODE_NAME}_${env.BRANCH_NAME}", inversePrecedence: true) {
      milestone 1
      sh "fastlane build_release"
    }
}
```

From: https://www.quernus.co.uk/2016/10/19/lockable-resources-jenkins-pipeline-builds/

Comment: Using the code, I got the following error: >>Unknown stage section "lock". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block.<< I moved the "lock" section into a "steps" section, then it worked.

Comment: What is the meaning of `inversePrecedence: true` while creating a `lock` ?

Comment: @Yash from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/) > By default waiting builds get the lock in the same order they requested to acquire it. By checking this option the newest build in the waiting queue will get the lock first.

Comment: While this is not what the OP asked for, this solution can be used to **prevent parallel execution of the subset of your build steps** and in this aspect it exceeds the solution of locking the full build with `disableConcurrentBuilds()`

Answer (score 41):

Example using options block in the declarative pipeline syntax:

```
pipeline {

  options { 
    disableConcurrentBuilds() 
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I think there are more than just one approach to this problem.

### Pipeline

- Use latest version of [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) and its `lock` step, as suggested in other answer.
- If building the same project:

  - Uncheck `Execute concurrent builds if necessary`.
- If building different projects:

  - Set different `node` or `label` for each project.

### Jenkins

- Limit number of node's executors to `1`?

### Plug-ins

- [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) - supposedly supports Pipeline projects
- [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) - not compatible with Pipeline projects

Comment: @sorin Can you be a little more specific about what you want to accomplish here?

Comment: Limiting number of node executors is impossible as they are needed for other jobs. I just want to prevent same repository from being build in parallel.

Comment: Any idea on how to uncheck `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` from a `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: The "Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin" now does have Pipeline support. Please see my answer below.

Comment: +1 to _Limit number of node's executors to 1_ - that is one of the best optimize a Jenkins installation.

Comment: @luka5z - how do you all these steps in JenkinsFile as I'm using multibranch project and the UI doesn't have all these options?

Answer (score 17):

The "[Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin)" now supports pipeline since `throttle-concurrents-2.0`. So now you can do something like this:

Fire the pipeline below twice, one immediately after the other and you will see. You can do this manually by double-clicking ***"Build Now"*** or by invoking it from a `parallel` step in another job.

```
stage('pre'){
    echo "I can run in parallel"
    sleep(time: 10, unit:'SECONDS')
}
throttle(['my-throttle-category']) {
    
    // Because only the node block is really throttled.
    echo "I can also run in parallel" 
    
    node('some-node-label') {
        
        echo "I can only run alone"
        
        stage('work') {
            
            echo "I also can only run alone"
            sleep(time: 10, unit:'SECONDS')
            
        }
    }
}
stage('post') {
    echo "I can run in parallel again"
    // Let's wait enough for the next execution to catch
    // up, just to illustrate.
    sleep(time: 20, unit:'SECONDS')
}
```

From the pipeline stage view you'll be able to appreciate this:

[image]

However, please be advised that this only works for `node` blocks within the `throttle` block. I do have other pipelines where I first allocate a node, then do some work which doesn't need throttling and then some which does.

```
node('some-node-label') {

    //do some concurrent work

    //This WILL NOT work.
    throttle(['my-throttle-category']) {
        //do some non-concurrent work
    }
}
```

In this case the `throttle` step doesn't solve the problem because the `throttle` step is the one inside the `node` step and not the other way around. In this case [the lock step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#lock-lock-shared-resource) is better suited for the task

Comment: I get "One or more specified categories do not exist", where do you specify the categories?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

Install Jenkins [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin).

In your pipeline script wrap the part in the lock block and give this lockable resource a name.

```
lock("test-server"){
    // your steps here
}
```

Use the name of whatever resource you are locking. In my experience its usually a test server or test database.

Comment: Just to add - I found the lock feature but didn't think it solved my issue. However you can use variable names to define the lock resource - using env.NODE_NAME solved my issue where I needed to lock a stage to not run concurrently on the same node (it could run concurrently on different nodes)

Comment: If there's an exception or timeout inside the lock, it seems that the lock is never released and the other concurrent build keeps running... Until it timesout... :( Not sure but that's what I'm observing

Answer (score 6):

If you're like my team then you like having user-friendly parameterized Jenkins Jobs that pipeline scripts trigger in stages, instead of maintaining all that declarative/groovy soup. Unfortunately that means that each pipeline build takes up 2+ executor slots (one for the pipeline script and others for the triggered job(s)) so the danger of deadlock becomes very real.

I've looked everywhere for solutions to that dilemma, and `disableConcurrentBuilds()` only applies to the one pipeline where it is used - it prevents the pipeline from running two jobs at the same time. It won't have any impact on other pipelines.

A hacky (yet surprisingly elegant) solution for us was to limit the master node's executors to 1 and make the pipeline scripts stick to using it (and only it), then hook up a local slave agent to Jenkins in order to take care of all other jobs.

Comment: Sorry, but this leads to mismanaging your employer's resources... How hard is it to imagine nodes with a triple number of CPU cores?

Answer (score 3):

One of the options is to use Jenkins REST API. I researched for another options, but seems that this is only one available with pipelines functionality.

You should write script which polls Jenkins for info of current jobs running and check whether job of same type is running.
To do this you should use Jenkins REST API, documentation you may find in the right bottom corner in your Jenkins page.
Example script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# this script waits for integration test build finish
# usage: ./wait-for-tests.sh <jenkins_user_id> <jenkins_user_token_id>
jenkins_user=$1
jenkins_token=$2
build_number=$3

job_name="integration-tests"
branch="develop"

previous_build_number=build_number
let previous_build_number-=1
previous_job_status=$(curl -s http://${jenkins_user}:${jenkins_token}@jenkins.mycompany.com/job/mycompany/job/${job_name}/branch/${branch}/${previous_build_number}/api/json | jq -r '.result')

while [ "$previous_job_status" == "null" ];
do
    previous_job_status=$(curl -s http://${jenkins_user}:${jenkins_token}@jenkins.mycompany.com/job/mycompany/job/${job_name}/branch/${branch}/${previous_build_number}/api/json | jq -r '.result')
    echo "Waiting for tests completion"
    sleep 10
done

echo "Seems that tests are finished."
```

I've used bash here, but you may use any language.
Then just call this script inside of your Jenkinsfile:

```
sh "./wait-for-tests.sh ${env.REMOTE_USER} ${env.REMOTE_TOKEN} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

So it will wait until job completion (don't be confused with integration-test mentions, it's just job name).

Be also aware that in rare cases this script may cause deadlock when both jobs are waiting for each other, so you may want to implement some max retry policies here instead of infinite waiting.

Comment: Polling is A. Inefficient.  and B. subject to race conditions.  Moreover the "previous build" may in fact be a prior-prior build. How? Imagine I start 3 simultaneous builds with different parameters all at once.  By the time the third build gets around to checking build #2, build #2 may have aborted (due to a parameter or job construction). Now build 3 thinks its in the clear because it doesn't see build #1.  It's also possible that someone DELETED the prior build before build #3 got around to checking. Or it may have been auto-disposed of by log retention rules. Meanwhile 1 is still running.

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused what's your suggestions?
Btw, while I don't use Jenkins for a long time, this script flawelessy worked and solved my problem.

Comment: The question was: "How do I prevent two pipeline jenkins jobs of the same type to run in parallel on the same node?"  My suggestion is to not use the solution in your answer. It doesn't prevent simultaneous builds, contains a race condition, requires a token and can block indefinitely. The solutions in other answers are reliable. (e.g. Restrict all nodes to single executors; Use Throttling; Use Locks; disable concurrent builds)

Answer (score 1):

Until the "Throttle Concurrent Builds" plugin [has Pipeline support](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31801), a solution would be to effectively run one executor of the master with a label that your job requires.

To do this, create a new node in Jenkins, for example an SSH node that connects to localhost. You could also use the command option to run slave.jar/swarm.jar depending on your setup. Give the node one executor and a label like "resource-foo", and give your job this label as well. Now only one job of label "resource-foo" can run at a time because there is only one executor with that lable. If you set the node to be in use as much as possible (default) and reduce the number of master executors by one, it should behave exactly as desired without a change to total executors.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the node configuration and set the property **Number of executors** to 1.

Comment: This answer best addresses the question that was asked, but it does duplicate one of the [3 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36487614/1655780) @luka5z provided years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin" you need to update plugin to the latest version (above 1.86.0) and enable "Allow several triggers per build" within Job configurations.