# How to prevent multiple pipelines from running concurrently?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins pipeline is running on a local server with limited ram. I have limited ram and have around 5 pipelines, for testing purposes I've pointed them to the same repository for now. When I open a PR, it triggers all 5 pipelines at the same time and causes throttling on my server.

I've tried these questions so far:

First, I've tried adding an [option to jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454130/how-do-i-prevent-two-pipeline-jenkins-jobs-of-the-same-type-to-run-in-parallel-o/43963315#43963315) by adding this:

```
options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
```

But this seems to only prevent same node concurrency.

There is also the option to [edit configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747580/disable-concurrent-builds) of my job which again seems to only effect a single job.

There is the [throttle add on](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/) but I haven't quite figured how to use it and frankly I'm not sure whether it effects multiple pipelines or not.

Comment: Is limiting the amount of available parallel agents / executors overall in Jenkins not an option? So no situation could throttle your server and parallel triggered jobs will be queued.

Comment: @cyberbrain I guess it is, how do I limit that?

Comment: This depends on your plans for your Jenkins server - did you set it up to do some tests locally for a limited period of time or do you plan to extend it in the future? Probably the official docs [Managing Nodes](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/) would be a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

The throttle concurrent build plugin is what you are looking for.
It will allow you to define throttle categories globally in your server and to assign these categories to your pipeline using the dedicated step.
The global setting enables to define a max number of parallel jobs per category.