# Build only latest commit on branch with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

This seems too trivial to ask, but I could not find an answer:

In a Multibranch Pipeline project (controlled by Jenkinsfile):
How can I skip previous builds on a branch, if there is a newer one and only build the latest commit and/or the tip of the branch?

```
     Build is running        
  ├────────────────────┤

o────────o────────o────────o
↑        ↑        ↑        ↑
Build    Skip     Skip     Build this


──────────────────────────────────>
                              (t)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent two pipeline jenkins jobs of the same type to run in parallel on the same node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454130/how-do-i-prevent-two-pipeline-jenkins-jobs-of-the-same-type-to-run-in-parallel-o)

Comment: No, parallel jobs from the same repository is wanted behavior. But only one build per branch.

Comment: Lockable resource with the lock name including `env.BRANCH_NAME`?

Comment: @StephenKing you mean by using this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin Wouldn't this also result in skipping the intermediate commits?

Comment: Your problem seems to be too trivial to understand. I don't get your intention. What do you mean by "skip a commit"?

Comment: The builds are quite complex. One build takes 2 hours to run, so the queue runs full. Therefore previous commits on the same branch should be skipped.

Comment: Ah, I see, of course the build will just be queued up with locks. Maybe together with the milestone step, but I'm not sure if that would help to only build the latest commit, once an older one is finished.

Comment: There was some throttle build plugin...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I have left the company and do not use Jenkins anymore. I have not found a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - abort running build if new one is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760716/jenkins-abort-running-build-if-new-one-is-started)

Comment: A solution involves cancelling current running builds when a new commit is pushed, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760716/jenkins-abort-running-build-if-new-one-is-started/44326216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins built-in `workflow-job-plugin` has [`disableConcurrentBuilds`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#:%7E:text=options%20%7B%20checkoutToSubdirectory(%27foo%27)%20%7D-,disableconcurrentbuilds,-Disallow%20concurrent%20executions) directive that takes one `boolean` parameter named `abortPrevious`. The parameter is undocumented in the [official Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#:%7E:text=options%20%7B%20checkoutToSubdirectory(%27foo%27)%20%7D-,disableconcurrentbuilds,-Disallow%20concurrent%20executions) but is mentioned in the [PR to the `workflow-job-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/pull/200#issue-934189735) and available since [version 2.42](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/releases/tag/workflow-job-2.42) of the aforementioned plugin.

Having that in mind the feature to cancel previous builds can be enabled in Jenkins by:

- using *Scripted Pipeline*:

  ```
  node {
      properties([
          disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
      ])
      [...]
  }
  ```
- using *Declarative Pipeline*:

  ```
  pipeline {
      agent any
      options {
          disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
      }
      stages { ... }
  }
  ```