# Pipeline : Folder has an appended @number after checkout from SVN

Tags: jenkins, svn, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am checking out a folder from one SVN location onto 3 different VMs. The folder "MakeBelieve" has to be checked out. So I use the Groovy syntax:

```
checkout([
$class: 'SubversionSCM',
additionalCredentials: [],
excludedCommitMessages: '',
excludedRegions: '',
excludedRevprop: '',
excludedUsers: '',
filterChangelog: false,
ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
includedRegions: '',
locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
depthOption: 'infinity',
ignoreExternalsOption: true,
local: 'MakeBelieve',
remote: 'svn_url_to_be_removed']],
workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
```

Out of the 3 Virtual Machines, on 2 machines it is being checked out as MakeBelieve. But on one of the machines it is being checked as MakeBelieve@2. Don't know why this is happening. The parallel stage is stated as:

```
stage('Check Out Code') {
        parallel {                
            stage('Checkout in Machine1') {
                agent {
                    label "Machine1"
                }
                steps {
                    echo 'Check out code '
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                    additionalCredentials: [],
                     excludedCommitMessages: '',
                     excludedRegions: '',
                     excludedRevprop: '',
                     excludedUsers: '',
                     filterChangelog: false,
                     ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                     includedRegions: '',
                     locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     depthOption: 'infinity',
                     ignoreExternalsOption: true,
                     local: 'MakeBelieve',
                     remote: 'svn_url']],
                     workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])                 
                }
            }               
            stage('Checkout in Machine2') {
                agent {
                    label "Machine2"
                }
                steps {
                    echo 'Check out code in'
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                        additionalCredentials: [],
                        excludedCommitMessages: '',
                        excludedRegions: '',
                        excludedRevprop: '',
                        excludedUsers: '',
                        filterChangelog: false,
                        ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                        includedRegions: '',
                        locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        depthOption: 'infinity',
                        ignoreExternalsOption: true,
                        local: 'MakeBelieve',
                        remote: 'svn_url']],
                        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])          
                }               
            }
            stage('Checkout in Machine3') {
                agent {
                    label "Machine3"
                }
                steps {
                    echo 'Check out code in'
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                        additionalCredentials: [],
                        excludedCommitMessages: '',
                        excludedRegions: '',
                        excludedRevprop: '',
                        excludedUsers: '',
                        filterChangelog: false,
                        ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                        includedRegions: '',
                        locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        depthOption: 'infinity',
                        ignoreExternalsOption: true,
                        local: 'MakeBelieve',
                        remote: 'svn_url']],
                        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])          
                }    
            }        
        }
    }
```

The folders should have the same name instead 2 machines have the correct folder and the last machine gets checked out as MakeBelieve@2. I need it to be MakeBelieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to concurrent builds. For every build that is started while one already is in progress, Jenkins appends an "@#concurrent build" to the workspace folder (I do not have a reference for this, just observation of my own setup). Maybe this SO question will solve your problem:

[How do I prevent two pipeline jenkins jobs of the same type to run in parallel on the same node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454130/how-do-i-prevent-two-pipeline-jenkins-jobs-of-the-same-type-to-run-in-parallel-o)